# How to control layering in HTML/CSS without making links nonfunctioning?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

For website:

```
http://68.50.243.1/wunhopkuendo/
```

I am trying to make the image carousel show UNDER the green banner on the top left. If I set z-index on the carousel to -1, the left/right buttons don't work. However if I set z-index to 999999 on the banner, it does not appear over the carousel. How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

JS Fiddle located:

http://jsfiddle.net/3ZSBh/

Comment: If you want us to look at a demo, post it to a site such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), where we can *see*, easily manipulate and change, the relevant code without digging through the web developer tools in our browsers.

Comment: Sure, but theres like 10 lines of code that arent twitter bootstrap

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZSBh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `position: relative` for the image.

```
<a class="brand" href="#">
    <img src="http://68.50.243.1/wunhopkuendo/img/logo.png"
         style="z-index: 99; position: relative;" />
</a>
```

The reason behind this is, the `z-index` works only on `position`ed elements, that are not `static`.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZSBh/1/

Answer (score 0):

The 'z-index' tends to work on elements that have the same type of `position` applied.

http://jsfiddle.net/CqnH4/1/

You can apply the following to your CSS:

```
.navbar {
    position:relative;
    z-index:999;
    height: 50px;
    background:#ff0;
}

#content{
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    width: 1024px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This would keep the navbar on top of the content...of course, you don't need to specify a `z-index` of `999`...you could simply go with a value of `2`.